# Line spacing and \enumerate with different list levels

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I have a list like this one:

[image: List]

I do not want to have spacing between lines (2) and (a), but I would like to keep spacing between (1) and (2) and between (b) and (3) (as on the photo). I tried to solve it by using LaTeX enumitem command `\begin{enumerate}[topsep=-5pt]` as shown below. I am interested in a similar command that can be used without giving the actual number for space height (`-5pt`), something like `nosep` (this one does not work) or so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(}\arabic*{)}]
    \item Random text
    \item Random text
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,topsep=-5pt]
        \item Random text
        \item Random text
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Random text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \itemsep is the additional vertical space between items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do, is to set `parsep` to zero. Unlike `itemsep`, which is the distance between two adjacent entries, `parsep` is the distance between an entry and a following paragraph. A nested list behaves actually the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(}\arabic*{)}, parsep=0pt]
    \item Random text
    \item Random text
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
        \item Random text
        \item Random text
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Random text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since a `parsep` is also added between adjacent items (see page 3 of the current [documentation for the `enumitem` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)), you probably want to keep it when there is no nested list. You can do this by first adding the value of `\parsep` to `\itemsep` and then (the order is important) set `parsep` to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(}\arabic*{)}, itemsep={\dimexpr\itemsep+\parsep\relax}, parsep=0pt]
    \item Random text
    \item Random text
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
        \item Random text
        \item Random text
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Random text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]